# Cannot Resolve Ammonite Main Methods in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ammonite, scala-script

I want to use `@main` like described here: https://ammonite.io/#ScriptArguments

```
@main
def all() = {
  ...
}
```

It cannot be resolved in Intellij. I couldn't find an import. I have added these dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
           "com.lihaoyi" %% "ammonite-ops" % "1.6.9",
           "com.lihaoyi" % "ammonite" % "1.6.9" cross CrossVersion.full
        )
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
import ammonite.main.Router.main

@main
def all() = {
  print("hey")
}

all()
```

Also, make sure you create `Scala Worksheet` (.sc) and not `Scala Class` (.scala) to allow IntelliJ to help you with ammonite imports.

Comment: thanks, it seems that Intellij shows the correct class but does not add the import when selected - might be a bug with Scala Scripts.

Comment: try to explicitly tell IntelliJ to treat .sc files as ammonite: [intellj preferences screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/7A7xT0B.png)